# A question about a solution to a differential equation and what the solution would look like

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given this differential equation:
$${dy\over dx}=-{x\over y}$$

And then this prompt: When does a solution $y=\phi(x)$ of the DE **increase at a faster rate?** You are **not** supposed to find the solution of the DE in order to answer this question. Answer the question **without using the solution.**

What does this mean? I know it's first order and separable, but I'm not sure if that's helpful here.

Comment: Try drawing the direction field: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field

Comment: @CheeHan Drawing the solution field is part D to this problem and my question was from part B, which leads me to believe that I'm not supposed to do that for the question I asked. Is there a "math-like" way to do this problem? (Sorry for saying "math-like," I'm just not sure what a better way to word that is)

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p7vd3cdmei